# repeating macro after sometime

Tags: text, macros, editor, text-editor

I need a text editor that capable of repeating macro after some time that i set.
Is there any of text editor that provide this functionality?

Comment: You can do it with Emacs, although you'll probably have to write your own Lisp code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ultraedit has this capability, if you are looking for an editor on Windows:

http://www.ultraedit.com/

Comment: are you sure?i set up ultraedit but i didn't see anything about that